# How can I update my current Apps without lose current existing record?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I have created a sample apps and install it on my site, and I have entered some data to my apps (lists record) and then I have updated some code on my Apps, and I don't know how can reinstall it to my site, without lose any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow an upgrade process to update the apps.

> For an update, you use the same product ID in the app manifest that
>   you used for the original version. The version number in the app
>   manifest should be greater than the version number of the original app
>   or the most recent update.

Following article at msdn describes it in detail:

[App for SharePoint update process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx)